# how to convert multiple EditText value into one date String in android studio?

Tags: android, datetime, android-edittext, jodatime, android-jodatime

its an age calculator project I need to know how to convert multiple EditText values into one date String in an android studio? keep in mind I am using "joda-time library" it's not showing the result. I don't know where I did a mistake! I have forgotten everything I can not fix now hope you guys can help me with that. thanks

```
public void dateOfBirth(){

    String day = editTextDay.getText().toString().trim();
    String month = editTextMonth.getText().toString().trim();
    String year = editTextYear.getText().toString().trim();

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String sDate = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;

    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String eDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);



    try {
       Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(sDate);
       Date date2 =simpleDateFormat.parse(eDate);
        /* long eDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(String.valueOf((eDate)));*/

        long startDate = date1.getTime();
        long endDate =date2.getTime();

        if (startDate<=endDate){

           Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
           int years = period.getYears();
           int months =period.getMonths();
           int days = period.getDays();

            textViewDay.setText(days);
            textViewMonth.setText(months);
            textViewYear.setText(years);

        }


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: You should provide a String to `setText`. Do `textViewDay.setText(String.valueOf(days));` instead.

Comment: i am bit confused with your comment can you please explain to me a little more details.

Comment: Since you are using Joda-Time, I recommend you go all-in and forget about the classes `Date` and`SimpleDateFormat`, which are poorly designed and troublesome. Joda-Time is far superior and offers all the functionality you need.

Comment: Please specify the expected result of your code and how observed result differs. Quote any error message literally. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* (from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Go all-in on Joda-Time

```
    String day = "11";
    String month = "4";
    String year = "2012";

    String sDate = "" + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    LocalDate dob = new LocalDate(sDate);

    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();

    if (dob.isBefore(today)) {
        Period period = new Period(dob, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
        int years = period.getYears();
        int months = period.getMonths();
        int days = period.getDays();

        System.out.println("" + years + " years " + months + " months " + days + " days");
    }
```

When I ran the above snippet just now, the output was:

> 7 years 10 months 0 days

Since you are interested in years, months and days, you don’t need `DateTime` objects (though they would work). They include time of day too. Just use `LocalDate`.

The classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. I recommend you stay away from those, and also from representing a point in time as a `long` count of milliseconds since the epoch. The good choices are:

1. Stay with Joda-Time since you are already using Joda-Time.
2. Migrate to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve my problem -

```
String day = editTextDay.getText().toString().trim();
    String month = editTextMonth.getText().toString().trim();
    String year = editTextYear.getText().toString().trim();

  //  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


    String BirthDate ="" + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    LocalDate sDate = new LocalDate(BirthDate);
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();

    Period period = new Period(sDate, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
    int years = period.getYears();
    int months =period.getMonths();
    int days = period.getDays();

    textViewDay.setText(""+days);
    textViewMonth.setText(""+months);
    textViewYear.setText(""+years);
```